# Android radio application stops playing when I turn the screen or when screensaver activates

Tags: android, shoutcast, gyroscope, background-music, android-music-player

I created an internet radio application which uses a SHOUTcast radio station and basically plays the predetermined internet radio station when I press Play button. It works fine but when I turn the screen the music pauses and I have to press Play again. It also pauses when the screen is locked after a while. How can I prevent the music to be stopped?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 issues: first, you are probably not properly handling the screen rotation/orientation changes. Take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) for some guidance on approaches to that. The second issue is that the network is probably being disconnected when the screen locks: you might need to grab a wake lock to prevent that or explicitly prohibit wifi sleeping. Take a look at this answer: [How do I keep Wifi from disconnecting when phone is asleep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871824/how-do-i-keep-wifi-from-disconnecting-when-phone-is-asleep) for some guidance on that.

Comment: Additionally, if you fireant want's to be able to use the device for anything else while listening, the playing should be done in a Service rather than an Activity.