# WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY_NEVER how to set in API-17?

Tags: android

I was using following code , my target is API-15

```
android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(cr, 
                        android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY, 
                        android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY_NEVER);
```

When the code runs on platform API-17 I get warnigns in the logcat,

Setting wifi_sleep_policy has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, value is unchanged.

So what I did after that was set my project target to APi-17 and used this code

```
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 17)
        {
            android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(cr, 
                        android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY, 
                        android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY_NEVER);
        }
        else            
        {               
            android.provider.Settings.Global.putInt(cr, 
                    android.provider.Settings.Global.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY, 
                    android.provider.Settings.Global.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY_NEVER);

        }
```

As a result I started getting following SecurityException in platform Api-17

```
         java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denial: writing to secure settings requires android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS
```

Then I checked that WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS permission is only for system apps and I was not able to compile my code with it, as if this permission is for system apps only.

So I am confused was the warning that I got earlier was wrong or is there anything wrong with my code, I want to make it compatible it with API-17.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is not possible to change this setting anymore from API-17 onward since it [has been deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY).

As you said, the `WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS` permission is only granted to system apps and so the best alternative is to ask the user to manually set this option from the wifi settings:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
```